# Access variable from different thread which is running parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, phantomjs, parallel.foreach

I have something like this:

```
int index = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(urls, ParOpt, (url) =>
{
  var currIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref index);                 
  var pjs = new PhantomJS();  //wrapper for PhantomJS
  pjs.Run(@"c:\script.js", new string[] { url});
});
```

What the above code does is to parallelly open some pages from urls list and increment currIndex variable. My question is:
Is it possible to read the value of currIndex by different Thread than the one that is executing the above code in App? Or is it possible to dermine which instance of Phantom opened the page?

Also, I don't want to use query string.

Comment: Did you try accessing `index`? What happened then?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `index` has the latest value at a given time, you can read that from other threads. Alternatively, you can try using a `ConcurrentDictionary` that maps a Url to an index. Your question is very vague, you should add details.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to read the value of currIndex by different Thread than the one that is executing the above code in App?

No. The `currIndex` variable is a local variable in your anonymous method for the parallel operation. It is visible only to the method itself, and cannot be directly accessed from any other thread.

> Or is it possible to dermine which instance of Phantom opened the page?

If you need for some other thread to be able to correlate a specific URL with a specific instance of the `PhantomJS` object, you can (as suggested in the comments above) use an instance of `ConcurrentDictionary<string, PhantomJS>` to provide a convenient way to retrieve the `PhantomJS` object for a given URL.

Do note that the `index` and `currIndex` variables, while they will provide a unique ID for each concurrent invocation of the anonymous method, will *not* necessarily provide an index relative to the order of the elements in the original `urls` collection. Differences in thread scheduling can lead to an invocation for a later element in the collection actually executing before an invocation for an earlier element in the collection.